# Python - Optimizing parsing large datasets

Tags: python, performance, cron

I have a data set names jobs that are currently running. I want to monitor them to see if they are running longer then normal, defined by thresholds.

- Each job has a average run time. I know the current time and start
  time. I have four conditions to evaluate and if true consider flag.

  1. average <5 min jobs = if they are running longer then 4x there average then flag.
  2. average >5<20 min job = running longer then 2x there average then flag
  3. average >20< 3 hours = running longer 1.5 there average then flag
  4. average >3 hours = running longer .5 there average then flag

Finally send all messages for all flag Jobs

> ```
>  flaged_jobs = [];
>     for job in job_bank:
>         if job.average_time < 5:
>             if (current_time - start_time) == 4 * (current_time - start_time):
>                 flaged_jobs.append(job)
>         elif job.average_time >= 5 and job.average_time < 20 :
>             if (current_time - start_time) == 2 * (current_time - start_time):
>                 flaged_jobs.append(job)
>         elif job.average_time >= 5 and job.average_time < 20 :
>             if (current_time - start_time) == 1.5 * (current_time - start_time):
>                 flaged_jobs.append(job)
>         else:
>             if (current_time - start_time) == .5 * (current_time - start_time):
>                 flaged_jobs.append(job)
>
>     for flaged in flaged_jobs:
>          send_message(flaged)
> ```

In regards to performance, what is the best way to handle this?  Is my pseudo code a good way to handle this?  Should incorporate a dict instead of list?  Jobs can range from a couple of hundred at one time to a couple of thousands. I'm limited to 2.6x python. What should I name this script as well, maybe runaway_jobs.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the best way!

But I think I can fix your code!

```python
 flaged_jobs = [];
    for job in job_bank:
        # first of all. get start_time from job status
        job_start_time = get_start_time(job)
        elapsed_time = current_time - job_start_time
        # Fix your logic, < 5 <=, < 20 <=...
        if job.average_time < 5:
            # (current_time - start_time) == 4 * (current_time - start_time)
            # is always False except current_time == start_time, so I fixed it.
            if elapsed_time >= 4 * job.average_time:
                flaged_jobs.append(job)
        elif 5 <= job.average_time < 20:
            if elapsed_time == 2 * job.average_time:
                flaged_jobs.append(job)
        elif 20 <= job.average_time < 3 * 60:
            if elapsed_time == 1.5 * job.average_time:
                flaged_jobs.append(job)
        elif 3 * 60 <= job.average_time:
            if elapsed_time == .5 * job.average_time:
                flaged_jobs.append(job)
        else:
            continue

    for flaged in flaged_jobs:
         send_message(flaged)
```

Comment: Thank you. What would you name the script?